# 2-D Static and Dynamic Array Passing

Tags: c++

Assume we have these declarations:

```
int** a;
int b[x][y];
```

Can I implement a function

```
foo f(bar c) {}
```

that lets me

```
f(a);
f(b);
```

without needing to overload it?

Comment: You could take a type that has two conversion constructors :p That kind of ruins the point, but it's not overloading that function.

Comment: I think if you understand the code a compiler generates for a multi-dimensional array reference, you can answer this yourself.  For b[i][j] the compiler generates *(b+i*y+j)  (or it might be *(b+j*x+i), I never remember).  Either way function f() will not know the dimensions of b[][] so it could not properly handle references to c[i][j].

Comment: These two types are _not_ compatible, so no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just use `void*` :)

And to answer your question, no. A multidimentional array is not the same as a pointer to a pointer. The reason is the indexing scheme. `int b [2][2]` is a continuous memory block of 4 integers. Indexing into it is equivalent to the following:

```
b[i][j] == *(b + 2*i + j)
```

The second dimension is part of the type defintion! The compiler knows that it only needs one dereference due to the memory layout of the array.

Meanwhile, for `int** a` the indexing is done like this:

```
a[i][j] == *(*(a+i)+j)
```

Comment: Do we really need the dangerously misleading first line?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, is it really misleading? I think it gets the point across that unless you want to give up all type information, you can't do what the OP asked about.